# How to show that the following identities about Conditional probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

If for p.m.f. $p$, $$p(x^*|x)=\int p(x^*|\theta)p(\theta|x)d\theta\varpropto\int \exp[-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x^*-\theta)^2]\exp[-\frac{1}{2\sigma'^2}(x^*-\theta')^2]$$
Why the following identity holds?

$$\mathbb{E}(x^*|x)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta, x)|x]=\mathbb{E}(\theta|x)=\theta'?$$
where $x^*|\theta$ is conditional independent with $x$.

Question: Why $\mathbb{E}(x^*|x)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta, x)|x]$ but not $\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta, x)|x]$?

Also,
\begin{align}
Var(x^*|x)=Var(\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta, x)|y)+\mathbb{E}(Var(x^*|\theta, x)|y)=??
\end{align}

> We know
> $$E(x)=E(E(x|y))$$ and
> $$Var(x)=E(Var(x|y))+Var(E(x|y))$$

Comment: The "identity΅$$Var(x^*|x)=Var(\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta, x)|y)+\mathbb{E}(Var(x^*|\theta, x)|y)$$does not make sense as the lhs is conditional on $x$ and the rhs on $y$. A correct version is $$Var(x^*|x)=Var(\mathbb{E}(x^*|\theta, x)|x)+\mathbb{E}(Var(x^*|\theta, x)|x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generalisation of Law of Total Variance and Total Expectation. Whenever something is given, you add it to every expected value and variance expression, i.e.$$\mathbb E[X|\mathcal Z]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y,\mathcal Z]|\mathcal Z]$$

As for your suggestion, $E[x^*|\theta]=E[E[x^*|x,\theta]|x]$ wouldn't make sense because LHS is a function of $\theta$ only, while RHS is a function of $x$ only.

If $x^*$ is conditionally independent from $x$ given $\theta$, then $\mathbb E[x^*|x,\theta]=\mathbb E[x^*|\theta]=\theta$ as per $p(x^*|\theta)$ suggests. This explains the $E[\theta|x]$ on the RHS of the equaton under the question "Why the following identity holds?". By the way, it should be $(\theta-\theta')^2$ in the integral, where $\theta'$ is probably a function of $x$.

Comment: How to get $\mathbb E[X|\mathcal Z]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y,\mathcal Z]|\mathcal Z]$?

Comment: It's given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#/Proof_in_the_general_case